# Get the smallest number from given digit

Tags: c++

i'm trying to get the smallest and the biggest number possible by rearanging the 3 digit number.

So i success get the biggest

```
int maxNumFromNum(int num) {
    int freq[10] = {0};
    string str = to_string(num);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        freq[str[i] - '0']++;
    int res = 0, mul = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        while (freq[i] > 0) {
            res = res + (i * mul);
            freq[i]--;
            mul = mul * 10;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

But now i'm trying to get the smallest one. How can be done that.

Example Outpots:

`321 Output> 123, 321`

`598 Output> 985, 598`.

And too, is there more efficiency way to do that?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: What about using `std::sort()` on the already obtained `std::string`, applying in descend order?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes. This is what i think. But is there any another ways to do that without converting the number to string

Comment: Sure, you may do the same by building a `std::vector<int>` for all the digits. I don't believe this would be better in performance, and way more cokplicated to obtain the digits.

Comment: I mean some other way, without using arrays at all

Comment: @parallela_Parl This will be even more complicated. What's wron with the simplest solution? Is this your homework, and aren't you allowed to use stuff from the standard library? Elaborate in your question regarding strict requirements please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Nope there's no limitations

Comment: @parallela_Parl Then I'd say go with `std::string` and `std::sort()`. That's short, well readable and probably best performance you can get.

Comment: If you want the program to do the exact same thing without using strings look at this: https://onlinegdb.com/SkAWuVIvD

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
  
int main() { 
    int n = 231;
    string s = to_string(n);
    sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    cout<<"Smaller: "<<s<<endl;
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    cout<<"Bigger : "<<s<<endl;
}
```

It works for integers of any size and runs in O(n lg(n)), where n is the number of digits of the integer.

Comment: How about without using strings?

Comment: Put each digit in an array, by using `% 10` and `/ 10`. Then, sort and print the sorted array forward and backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change the line:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
```

to

```
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void getBigAndSmall(string num, string &outBig, string outSmall){
    outBig = 0;
    outSmall = 0;

    //since you're sorting digits you can use this to sort them with O(n)
    //this would be faster than std::sort in this case.
    int bigArray[10] = {0};
    int smallArray[10] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        int digit = (int)num[i] - 48; //this might not be good idea.
        bigArray[digit]++;
        smallArray[digit]++;
    }
    
    int digitsSize = num.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < digitsSize; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            if (bigArray[j] > 0){
                bigArray[j]--;
                outBig += j;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 9; j > -1; j--){
            if (smallArray[j] > 0){
                smallArray[j]--;
                outSmall += j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This might have some mistakes, since I didn't test it, but it has a runtime O(n).

Comment: You probably should not use the magic number 48 instead '0' would be better.

Comment: no probably not, but '0' would just translate to 48 though, right?

Answer (score -1):

It gives max integer using input digits without using string

```
int extractMax(int num) {
    std::vector<int> digits;

    bool flag = false;
    int curDigit;
    while (num > 0) {
        curDigit = num % 10;
        num /= 10;
        flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.size(); ++i) {
            if (digits[i] > curDigit) {
                flag = true;
                digits.insert(digits.begin() + i, curDigit);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (not flag) digits.push_back(curDigit);
    }

    std::sort(digits.begin(), digits.end());

    int dec = 1, int_val = 0;
    for (auto& it : digits){
        int_val += it * dec;
        dec *= 10;
    }
    return int_val;
}
```

If you want to get smallest integer, change this line:

```
std::sort(digits.begin(), digits.end());
```

With this:

```
std::sort(digits.begin(), digits.end(), greater<int>());
```